# Apply same actions and animation to various instances AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to make something similar to a led screen and I want every dot (led) to light up when the mouse rolls over, every dot has the same animation (changing colors) and should work with the same code.

I've applied this code to various instances:

```
dot1.stop();
dot1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,dot1in);
dot1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,dot1out);


function dot1in(e:MouseEvent) :void {
dot1.play();
}

function pout(e:MouseEvent) :void {
dot1.stop();
}
```

so the second dot's actions look like this:

```
dot2.stop();
dot2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,dot2in);
dot2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,dot2out);


function dot2in(e:MouseEvent) :void {
dot2.play();
}

function dot2out(e:MouseEvent) :void {
dot2.stop();
}
```

This actually works, but I have around 300 dots and I would like to know if there's a more efficient way to do the same. Also if there's somehow to apply the same animation via coding, other than editing every timeline and copying the frames. Thanks.

Comment: You will want to use loops. This is a good tutorial on loops: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101-loops/ . You also don't need to apply a different function for each dot. The dot1in and dot1out function is sufficient for all your dots. You will use a loop to assign an eventListener to each dot, and they will all use just those two functions.

Comment: I used the loop for the eventListener and everything ok, the only problem is that I cannot use only dot1in and dot1out functions, mainly because all the other dots will start blinking when i just touch one of them... Thank you anyway.

Comment: Rewrite your dotIn and dotOut function a little bit so that the .play() and .stop() methods are called on the event.currentTarget, like so:
`e.currentTarget.play();`
This will make it so that the dot which called the function will display the animation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being an idiot here. Assign your currentTarget to another variable first, and then you do the .play on that variable. For example: `var tmpVar:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip`
Then you can do the .play and .stop on `tmpVar`

Comment: Make your LED a custom class, and put the functionality in that.

Comment: yep... I'm gonna try that... thanks.